# Pine script not plotting historic days

Tags: pine-script

my first indi script and it calculate properly but it doesn't plot past 2 days prior. So basically plots te current day but after that not plotting correctly. Any help here? Many thnks
[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Divergence", overlay=true)


tf_short = input(title="Timeframe",defval='15')
sym1_short = input(title="Symbol1", defval="eurusd"), res1 = tf_short, source11 = open, source12 = close, source13 = high, source14 = low
sym2_short = input(title="Symbol2", defval="gbpusd"), res2 = tf_short, source21 = open, source22 = close
open_price1 = request.security(sym1_short, res1, source11) 
close_price1 = request.security(sym1_short, res1, source12) 
high_price1 = request.security(sym1_short, res1, source13)
low_price1 = request.security(sym1_short, res1, source14)
open_price2 = request.security(sym2_short, res2, source21)
close_price2 = request.security(sym2_short, res2, source22)
down_bar2 = close_price2 < open_price2
up_bar2 = close_price2 > open_price2
up_bar1 = close_price1 > open_price1
down_bar1 = close_price1 < open_price1

up_bar = up_bar1 and down_bar2
down_bar = down_bar1 and up_bar2

color_up = color.new(color.green, transp = 80)
color_down = color.new(color.red, transp = 80)

box_offset_x = (timeframe.period == "5") ? -2 : (timeframe.period == "15") ? -1 : na  
box_offset_y = (timeframe.period == "5") ? -1 : (timeframe.period == "15") ? 1 : na 
line_offset_x = (timeframe.period == "5") ? -2 : (timeframe.period == "15") ? -2 : na  
line_offset_y = (timeframe.period == "5") ? +3 : (timeframe.period == "15") ? +6 : na 

if up_bar
    box.new(bar_index+box_offset_x, high_price1,bar_index+box_offset_y, low_price1, border_color=na , bgcolor=color_up )
    line.new(bar_index+line_offset_x, high_price1, bar_index+line_offset_y,  high_price1 , color=color_up)
    line.new(bar_index+line_offset_x, low_price1, bar_index+line_offset_y,  low_price1 , color=color_up)

if down_bar
    box.new(bar_index+box_offset_x, high_price1,bar_index+box_offset_y, low_price1, border_color=na , bgcolor=color_down )
    line.new(bar_index+line_offset_x, high_price1, bar_index+line_offset_y,  high_price1 , color=color_down)
    line.new(bar_index+line_offset_x, low_price1, bar_index+line_offset_y,  low_price1 , color=color_down)
```

Comment: So there is a limitation on drawing objects, old ones are deleted as garbage collection. To increase a max=500 you need to enter max_lines_count into the indicator().

Comment: Also, there’s no manual setting for max_lines_count. So to increase (or decrease) the maximum number of trend lines, we got to use this argument with the study() function or strategy() function.

Comment: Do you really need to use the `line` feature? Can't you do it with the `plot()` function?

Comment: plot() will draw a continuos line along the price, like a band. With line() my intention is to highlight the area.